# Increase size of font in bookmarks in Seamonkey

Tags: fonts, seamonkey

[image: Bookmarks screenshot]

I would like to be able to increase the size of the font used in the bookmarks file used in Seamonkey

Comment: Was imgur not working for you? Why link to dropbox?

Comment: Is something wrong with dropbox?

Comment: The default here, if you drag-n-drop an image is imgur. Anyway I fixed it and will be posting an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your file manager to open `/home/andy/.mozilla/seamonkey/k55ql4r2.default/chrome/` changing `andy` to your actual username and `k55ql4r2.default` to your actual profile's name.

Create a new **text** file in there named `userChrome.css` using the exact same spelling.

Paste in the following content:

```
/*
 * Do not remove the @namespace line -- it's required for correct functioning
 */
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"); 
/* set default namespace to XUL */

menupopup#bookmarksMenuPopup  * {
   font-size: 20pt !important
 }
```

You can change `20pt` to a higher or lower value to meet your specific needs.

Restart Seamonkey. That is essential.

**Before:**

[image: before editing userChrome.css]

**After:**

[image: after editing userChrome.css]